# Code not checking values in list?

Tags: python, list, function, input

This program I am trying to build needs to check if the user's input corresponds to values in a list. Here is the code I have:

```
def find_val(val, seq):
    for ele in seq:
        if val == ele:
            return True
    return False

def get_input(possible_vals, day_or_time_string):
    if day_or_time_string == "day":
        answer = input("What day would you like your appointment? ")
    else:
        answer = input("What time would you like your appointment? ")
    answer = answer.strip()
    valid_entry = find_val(answer, possible_vals)
    if valid_entry == True:
        count = 0
        while False:
            second_answer = input("Invalid entry. Please enter a valid day: ")
            count = count + 1
            if count == 3:
                print("This is getting silly - still not a valid entry")
            if second_answer in possible_vals:
                return second_answer
    else:
        return answer

day_list = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"]
res = get_input( day_list, "day" )
print("The funtion returned", res)
```

This is the type of output I should be getting:

```
What day would you like your appointment? saturday
Invaild entry. Please enter a valid day: Monday
The funtion returned Monday
```

However, it seems that no matter what I input, the function returns it, and doesn't check if the input matches a string in the list:

```
What day would you like your appointment? akw
The function returned akw
```

What is wrong with my code that isn't allowing the user's input to be checked whether or not it is in the list day_list?

Comment: Try to step through your code. What is the value of `valid_entry` if the `answer` is not in `possible_vals`, as is the case here?

Comment: `While False`... that's definitely a unique coding decision. I love code that is guaranteed to never run.

Answer (score 2):

First

```
valid_entry = find_val(answer, possible_vals)
if valid_entry == True:
```

can be simplified to

```
if answer in possible_vals:
```

(your `find_val` function is totally unnecessary)

Then your problem is that

```
while False: 
    ...
```

simply never executes... Did you mean `while True`? If so You'll need to somehow break out this (now) infinite loop using a `break` statement for example.

And finally as A.G. suggests, you explicitly tell your program to return `answer` when it's not "valid" so why do you expect otherwise?